# ‘!’ not meaningful for factors in R

Tags: r

I need to exclude the variable "PABI" from my data frame. So, I am subsetting as follow:

```
MyData4 <- subset(MyData, PROV=="PABI")
newdata <- MyData[!MyData4]
```

but I got this error:

```
Error in FUN(left) : invalid argument type
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
4: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
5: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
6: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
7: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
8: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘!’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Please provide additional details about your data.  Is `MyData` a factor?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do:

```
newdata <- subset(MyData, PROV!="PABI")
```

Answer (score 1):

`!` only applies to logical variables. However, your `subset` call returns a data.frame, not a logical; hence the error. In reality, you just need to invert the condition in your first line:

```
newdata <- subset(MyData, PROV != "PABI")
```

That’s it.

Just to clarify how logical values work, you could also write the following:

```
has_PABI <- MyData$PROV == "PABI"
newdata <- MyData[! has_PABI]
```

Notice that the second line is now identical to your code. What changed is that the variable you as a negative index is now a logical vector, containing the values `TRUE` or `FALSE` for each row, depending on the value of that row’s `PROV` column.

Comment: I think OP is using `subset` on a factor.  This doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: @BrodieG OP said “data.frame”, and since you cannot subset a factor, the error message would be different (“Error in subset.default(…)”). And with a data.frame you will in fact get exactly the error message in the question.

Comment: You can subset a factor: `subset(factor(letters), letters!="z")`

Comment: but, yes, your comment about the actual error is true.  It never occurred to me to negate a data frame.

Comment: I think you are right, though for the sake of being annoying, the error with a factor is actually the same ;) `factor(letters)[!factor(letters)]`

Comment: @BrodieG Fair enough. Didn’t even occur to me to check this.